# How to save images drawn with drawRect BEFORE VC.m tries to load them?

Tags: multithreading, image, load, save

Thanks for all the help this site has been to help answer many questions!

I overrode drawRect in subclass of UIView, drew a bunch of images and save them as PNGs.

Next I am trying to load the images for use in ViewController.m

Finally got animations working, but experienced a time when VC would try to load the images before Draw2D had saved them. Found that NSLog worked well to see sequence of events:

```
if ([self loadNamedImage:nameToLoad]) {
[image2set addObject:[self loadNamedImage:nameToLoad]];
NSLog(@"Loaded %@", nameToLoad8); }
```

loadNamedImage is the method that returns the loaded images.  Adding if/exist seemed to fix the problem for awhile, but I want to properly use something like

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:;

// where to place command, which object, etc?
```

tried using sleep statement in VC hoping the sleep time would be used to save the images before trying to load them .. how can the program startup sequence be adjusted enough to make this work?

dBC

Answer (score 0):

found that using viewDidAppear vs viewDidLoad solved my problem for awhile.

Recently started working with Gestures and reset simulator setting as suggested to fix finding needed files. Now the images won't load again because viewDidAppear tries to load pics before overridden DrawRect method draws them. Tried different restore points, clean project, and uninstall app from simulator to no avail :o(

Examples of where and how to implement addDependency, GCD or other solution are greatly appreciated!